# Opposite of UNION SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables :

```
interests (storing the interest ID and name)
person_interests(storing the person_id and interest_id)
```

How do I select all the interests that a particular person has not selected?

I have tried the following SQL Query and am still not getting the desired result

```
SELECT * 
  FROM interests LEFT JOIN person_interests 
               ON interests.id=person_interests.person_id
 WHERE person_interests.id IS NULL 
   AND person_id=66;
```

Comment: `except` is the opposite of `union`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM interests
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT person_interests.interest_id
        FROM person_interests
        WHERE person_id = 66
            AND interests.id = person_interests.interest_id
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from interests  
WHERE interest_id NOT IN  
(SELECT interest_id FROM person_interests WHERE person_id=66)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on.

First, *I think* you have an error in your join. Shouldn't it be `interests.id=person_interests.interest_id` instead of `interests.id=person_interests.person_id`?

That aside, I still don't think you would be getting the desired result because your person_id filter is on the RIGHT side of your LEFT OUTER join, thus turning it back into an inner join. There are several ways to solve this. Here's what I would probably do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SELECT interests.*, person_id 
  FROM interests LEFT JOIN person_interests 
       ON interests.id=person_interests.interest_id
   WHERE person_interests.id IS NULL )
WHERE person_id=66;
```